# Azure ADB2C signin-oidc failing in ASP.NET Core 2 web app

Tags: azure, asp.net-core-2.0, azure-ad-b2c

Hoping someone can help me out with a problem I am having with Azure AD B2C and an ASP.NET Core 2 web app.

The problem is with the signin-oidc route.

When I run it locally, everything works great, but when I push it to Azure, that page is returning a 400 error, see the screenshot below for more information:

[image]

Here is what it looks like running locally:

[image]

I am struggling with how to troubleshoot this problem. I have scoured the logs in the web app and the Audit Logs for the Azure ADB2C, and can’t seem to get to the root issue.

Here is my code for authentication:

```
services.AddAuthentication(options =>
{
    options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    options.DefaultSignInScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    options.DefaultChallengeScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
})
.AddCookie()
.AddOpenIdConnect("AzureADB2C", options =>
{
    options.Authority = Configuration.GetValue<string>("AzureADB2COptions:Authority");
    options.ClientId = Configuration.GetValue<string>("AzureADB2COptions:ClientId");
    options.ClientSecret = Configuration.GetValue<string>("AzureADB2COptions:ClientSecret");
    options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
    options.MetadataAddress = Configuration.GetValue<string>("AzureADB2COptions:MetadataAddress");

    options.ResponseType = OpenIdConnectResponseType.IdToken;

    options.Scope.Clear();
    options.Scope.Add("openid");

    options.CallbackPath = new PathString(
        Configuration.GetValue<string>("AzureADB2COptions:CallbackPath"));

    options.ClaimsIssuer = "AzureADB2C";

    options.TokenValidationParameters =
        new TokenValidationParameters
        {
            NameClaimType = "name"
        };

    options.Events = new OpenIdConnectEvents
    {
        OnAuthorizationCodeReceived = (context) =>
        {
            return Task.CompletedTask;
        },
        OnAuthenticationFailed = (context) =>
        {
            return Task.CompletedTask;
        },
        OnTokenResponseReceived = (context) =>
        {
            return Task.CompletedTask;
        },
        OnTokenValidated = async (context) =>
        {
            if (context.SecurityToken is JwtSecurityToken token)
            {
                if (context.Principal.Identity is ClaimsIdentity identity)
                {
                    ...
                }
            }
        }
    };
});
```

Like I said, it works locally, just not in Azure.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Where you have the `ClientId` and `ClientSecret`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the problem, embarrassed to say it had nothing to do with Azure ADB2C, thought it was the signin-oidc that was supposedly bombing out.

I wired up AppInsights, specifically the Live Metrics Stream and was able to figure out the issue ... it was caused by a misspelled AppSetting.

Thanks to everyone who took a minute to look at this, instead of deleting this question,

I'll leave it here, maybe save someone else an embarrassing question or two.

Comment: Hi @MarileeTurscak-MSFT ... I will, just have to wait two days before the system will let me. :)